# Facing problems with Google event tracking code for link Clicks

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to trigger event when user clicks on the link. The code I am using is this

```
<a href="https://www.businessxb.com/" 
gtag('event', 
     'tosubscribe',
     {'event_category':'subscribe', 'event_label':'subscribe for notifications'});="">
  Business opportunities in Dubai
</a>
```

But I am not getting any event recorded in Google Analytics

Comment: How long did you wait before checking Google anlaytics for the data?

Comment: @DaImTo Few hours

Answer (score 0):

Due to processing latency it can take between 24 - 48 hours for data to appear in the standard reports.

Check the real-time reports if you are seeing hits there your code is probably working.   Just wait the data should appear in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

As DalmTo pointed out, you code is indeed seems to be incorrect. It's not specified, when gtag command should be fired. More precisely, it is not bound to `onClick` event. You should use something like this. (I've not tested the gtag part, just added the onClick syntax.)

```
   <a href="https://www.businessxb.com/" 
      onclick="gtag('event', 
                    'tosubscribe',
                    {'event_category':'subscribe', 'event_label':'subscribe for notifications'});">
    Business opportunities in Dubai
  </a>
```